# angularjs - ng-if with array key and result from function

Tags: angularjs, angular-ng-if

I'm trying to use an ng-if within a repeater. Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
<li ng-repeat="timers in current.Timer | groupBy: 'day' | toArray:true | orderBy: '$key'" class="details-single-day" ng-click="editView('/edit')" ng-if="timers.$key==isToday()">
   <span class="details-day-name">Day: {{timers.$key}}</span>
   <bars timer="timers" day="timers.$key" title="Week"></bars>
</li>
```

isToday() function returns today as an int:

```
$scope.isToday = () ->
  return new Date().getDay()
```

Basically, I want to display my values if `$key` (from 0 to 6) is equal to `isToday()` result.

Without the `ng-if`, i can see all the details for everyday, including `{{timer.day}}` as int.

But with the ng-if, nothing at all is displayed.

Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you make a fiddle reproducing this?

Comment: Ok, give me a second

Comment: You might want to check `timers.$key`'s value, and try putting things like `1 == isToday()` or `6 == isToday()`  in the `ng-if`

Comment: @Komo, if i type 1==isToday() I still cannot see anything, but i should as isToday returns 1

Comment: @Nick then `isToday()` isn't returning what it should be. Remove `ngIf` and place `isToday()` inside the `ngRepeat` loop to see the outputed value and let us know.

Comment: @CosminAbabei isToday() is actually returning 1

Comment: Try putting inside the `li` : `<span>{{ timers.$key == isToday() }}</span>`,  `<span>{{ timers.$key }}</span>` `<span>{{ isToday() }}</span>` and give us the output

Comment: The result is: false, 0, {the third values is not displayed}, repeated from 0 to 6 and always false

Comment: Refer: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4398

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve this, and it was really simple.

Instead of doing:

```
<li ng-repeat="timers in current.Timer | groupBy: 'day' | toArray:true | orderBy: '$key'" class="details-single-day" ng-click="editView('/edit')" ng-if="timers.$key==isToday()">
   <span class="details-day-name">Day: {{timers.$key}}</span>
   <bars timer="timers" day="timers.$key" title="Week"></bars>
</li>
```

using a function (isToday), I did this instead:

```
<li ng-repeat="timers in current.Timer | groupBy: 'day' | toArray:true | orderBy: '$key'" class="details-single-day" ng-click="editView('/edit')" ng-if="timers.$key == today">
   <span class="details-day-name">Day: {{timers.$key}}</span>
   <bars timer="timers" day="timers.$key" title="Week"></bars>
</li>
```

where today is not a function anymore:

```
$scope.today = new Date().getDay()
```

and now it works perfectly. Thanks to everyone for your help

Answer (score 0):

It seems you cannot use `ng-repeat` and `ng-if` on the same element.
I've put up a fiddle for you to see : http://jsfiddle.net/bh83jc4b/2/

I suggest filtering your array using plain javascript (as in the fiddle) or a custom filter.

```
 $scope.filtered = $scope.current.Timer.filter(function (timers) {
      return timers.$key === $scope.isToday();
 });

<li ng-repeat="timers in filtered | groupBy: 'day' | toArray:true | orderBy: '$key'" class="details-single-day" ng-click="editView('/edit')">
   <span class="details-day-name">Day: {{timers.$key}}</span>
   <bars timer="timers" day="timers.$key" title="Week"></bars>
</li>
```

Comment: With the custom filter i get this error: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined